# Problem with PPA upload. GPG signature: Verification failed 3 times

Tags: ppa

I'm trying to upload a package to ppa, but I get the error message (it is in the end of this post). I've created the ppa and tried to upload a signed package and I got the error. I thought that this is because I don't have my ssh key in the settings, so I've added one. But the problem is still here.

What should I do to upload my package to ppa?

```
bessarabov@bessarabov-note:~/tmp/delete_after_2011-05-08$ dput ppa:bessarabov/star libsql-easy-perl_0.02-1_i386.changes
Checking signature on .changes
gpg: Signature made Sun 08 May 2011 01:36:39 PM MSD using RSA key ID 79B2238B
gpg: Good signature from "Ivan Bessarabov "
Good signature on /home/bessarabov/tmp/delete_after_2011-05-08/libsql-easy-perl_0.02-1_i386.changes.
Checking signature on .dsc
gpg: Signature made Sun 08 May 2011 01:36:24 PM MSD using RSA key ID 79B2238B
gpg: Good signature from "Ivan Bessarabov "
Good signature on /home/bessarabov/tmp/delete_after_2011-05-08/libsql-easy-perl_0.02-1.dsc.
Uploading to ppa (via ftp to ppa.launchpad.net):
  Uploading libsql-easy-perl_0.02-1.dsc: done.
  Uploading libsql-easy-perl_0.02-1.tar.gz: done.
  Uploading libsql-easy-perl_0.02-1_all.deb: done.
  Uploading libsql-easy-perl_0.02-1_i386.changes: 1k/2k550 Changes file must be signed with a valid GPG signature: Verification failed 3 times: ["(7, 9, u'No public key')", "(7, 9, u'No public key')", "(7, 9, u'No public key')"] : Permission denied.
Note: This error might indicate a problem with your passive_ftp setting.
      Please consult dput.cf(5) for details on this configuration option.                                                                                bessarabov@bessarabov-note:~/tmp/delete_after_2011-05-08$
```

Comment: Could be a bug/problem on launchpad itself:  https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/152715 (see comment #2).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. After adding my OpenPGP everything is ok.

More details on the discussion https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/156588